# How to track additional post data using Ahoy gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, ahoy

I am using Ahoy gem to track article visits on my rails app. Ahoy save lot of visit data by default, for example **landing_page** url. Is there way to get and save to visits table additional post data, for example post title, which not comes by default?

Thanks!

Comment: You still looking for it? I have the solution if you do so. Or want to accept a answer for your question

Comment: @Rubioli - please add it, I'd like to see.

Comment: @MikeBuckbee Please create a question and send me the link here and I'll add the answer there. doesn't look like he is accepting any answer

Comment: @Rubioli yes, I have found a solution. But if you have an answer, why you don't want to post it for other people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to get and save whatever you want. Take a look at this:
https://github.com/ankane/ahoy#events

In the `properties` object you can specify any kind of data that you wish to track.

Comment: Founded a long time ago but still thank you for the answer. Can be useful for others.